# finding repeated letters in a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string in which i want to find the repeated letters. For example,

```
A <- c('A-B-A-B-C', 'A-B-C-D', 'A-B-A-C-D-E-F', 'A-B-A-B')
```

I want to create a vector `B` which takes a value of 0 if there is no repetition of letters, 1 otherwise.

```
B <- c('1','0','1','1')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine `strsplit` and `anyDuplicated` in base R to get close to what you want.

```
sapply(strsplit(A, "-"), anyDuplicated, fixed=TRUE)
[1] 3 0 3 3
```

`anyDuplicated` returns the first index of the duplicated value. As @rich-scriven notes, adding `fixed=TRUE` to the `strsplit` function should increase efficiency as it does a literal mapping (no regular expressions involved)

You could wrap this in `pmin` to get your desired result:

```
pmin(sapply(strsplit(A, "-", fixed=TRUE), anyDuplicated), 1)
[1] 1 0 1 1
```

or as @rich-scriven notes, use `sign` to convert the values.

```
sign(sapply(strsplit(A, "-", fixed=TRUE), anyDuplicated))
[1] 1 0 1 1
```